# Intel Q45 graphics will not send correct resolution to second (DP) monitor

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, display, displayport, intel-graphics

System is Lenovo 9964-A7U with Intel Q45 graphics running Windows XP.

Monitors are both 17" Acer V173 with native resolution of 1280x1024. Both use VGA connectors. Secondary monitor is connected using Display Port to VGA adapter.

In windows display properties, I can set both monitors to 1280x1024, but only monitor 1 (connected directly using onboard VGA connector) actually displays this native resolution. Monitor 2 (connected to DP using DP-to-VGA adapter) is actually sent 1024x768 with "scrolling" to allow the viewing of the parts of the 1280x1024 picture being sent.

I have installed the monitor drivers and Display Properties shows correct resolution for both monitors and appears to think everything is OK.

I have also installed the latest drivers from Lenovo as well as drivers provided by Intel for use when the native resolution is not properly detected using their normal drivers, but the issue persists.

I have also updated system BIOS as these DP ports and power management seem to have disagreements at times.

Does anybody know how I can coax the Intel drivers to send a regular 1280x1024 native resolution picture to the secondary monitor without it assuming the monitor cannot really handle it?

Other systems with same configuration work OK and send correct native resolution without issues.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the DP-to-VGA converter causing this?  (I'm not sure how specific you're being about "other systems with same configuration")

Comment: Exact same configuration as in, one monitor connected directly to VGA, second monitor connected to DP port via DP-to-VGA adapter.

Comment: If they're identical converters then I'm fairly stumped; I've no experience with converting DP to analog but it's pretty weird.  Just wanted to make sure the obvious wasn't getting overlooked. :)

Comment: Did you try using another DP->VGA converters to rule out it out?

Comment: I'm going to have to wait a few days before I can try a different adapter. I took long enough trying to deploy it yesterday and this is a busy time for that user. Probably sometime next week I'll be able to try a different adapter.

Comment: @techie007: this turned out to be the case, kind of. I tried a second adapter on the problem machine, rebooted, and the correct resolution worked properly. To further test, then, I connected the problem adapter to an identical system and it configured and displayed properly without issue. If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shinrai also suggests, it sounds like a faulty DP->VGA adapter dongle.

Perhaps try using another of the DP->VGA converters to rule out it out?